# Text Comparison from user input and a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a userform in excel and want to do a comparison of two inputs from a previous section of the userform which will enable a command button if the texts match. I'm a noob to VBA and have got quite a bit of what I want to do to work but this part has me stumped (I assume it is my lack of all things programming that is why I can't figure this out).  Here are the basics of what I want to do: user is required to put in their first name and last name (plus lots of other stuff), click some boxes then read a statement and check the box they read it and type in their name again to a text box (like a signature verify type thing), thus comparing first and last name from page 1 to what the user is typing into the signature text box. Then when this is verified the "save" function is enabled. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Public Fname As String
Public Lname As String

Private Sub Cmd_HI_Click()

Fname = txt_Fname.Value
Debug.Print Fname
Lname = txt_Lname.Value
Debug.Print Lname
'lots of other code here
end sub

Private Sub TB_electronicSignature_Change()
If TB_electronicSignature.Value = Fname & Lname Then
cmd_add.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

I can add more if it's needed but that's the gist of it, I figure that I have to do WAY more than I am to get the verify to work than simply asking if the Fname and Lname are true. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this a [missile launch interface](https://xkcd.com/970/)?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. If your question is "What other validations should I perform in order to verify the user?", then this isn't a programming question; it's a business rule question, or possibly an [information security](http://security.stackexchange.com) question. If the question is "I'm getting a compiletime or runtime error" or "The code isn't working like I expect it to", then this is the right place, but you should provide more information, like what the error is, or how the actual behavior is different from your expectations.

Comment: Bazinga, well played!

Comment: Not so much an error but I'm not getting the "save" function button to show up because the comparison of the first and last name isn't the same, and I'm not sure why they aren't...probably a simple chair keyboard interface issue though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't explain what the problem is, but I figure it's not becoming visible.
The Electronic Signature box presumably would have a space between the first and last name, so you should use:

```
If TB_electronicSignature.Value = Fname & " " & Lname Then
cmd_add.Visible = True
```

Comment: I guess that would be useful information, I want the "save button" to become visible. thanks!